# IBM Worklight 6.1.0.0: Android environment missing some files

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

Steps:

1. Create a sample application "SampleApp" and add "android" environment to it.
2. Delete the "native" folder from the android environment. e.g. SampleApp/android/native
3. Right click on "android" folder and do - Run As -> Build Android Environment

Observe:

Following files are missing from the "native/libs" folder

1. android-async-http.jar
2. guava.jar

I didn't found any other way to include these files. On actual android device (Samsung Tab 3), "guava.jar" file is needed to initialize JSONStore object.

Comment: Do you have the latest update?  When I rebuild after deleting the native folder, this 2 libraries are added back automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Update April 2nd, 2014: From the comments to this answer:*

> I have upgraded to Worklight 6.1.0.1. Now the issue is reproducible in
>   following scenario - 1. Instead of "native" folder, just delete these
>   2 files (android-async-http.jar, guava.jar) 2. rebuild the android
>   environment.

This is OK. The native folder is considered the user's domain. That means that if a user decides to remove parts of it - for example .jars from the lib\ folder, to maybe... reduce the app's filesize? that's okay. It is the user's responsibility.

---

I have tested this in Worklight 6.1.0.1; created a new project and application, added the Android environment, Run As > Run on Worklight Development Server.

The supposed missing files are in my android\native\libs folder:

[image]

Comment: Yes, we have JSONStore and Analytics in Optional Features. Even though, those files are not getting added in "native/libs" folder.

Comment: I have upgraded to Worklight 6.1.0.1. Now the issue is reproducible in following scenario -

1. Instead of "native" folder, just delete these 2 files (android-async-http.jar, guava.jar)

2. rebuild the android environment.

Comment: This is OK. The native folder is considered the user's domain. That means that if a user decides to remove parts of it - for example .jars from the lib\ folder, to maybe... reduce the app's filesize? that's okay. It is the user's responsibility.